# R - procedural call to a function in a list

Tags: r, list, function

I'm having troubles in creating a procedural call to a function that is element of a list.

I have a list of functions of the type

```
> initial
$g452
function (v) 
.approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f)
<bytecode: 0x06bd04e8>
<environment: 0x06c7a4c8>

$g664
function (v) 
.approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f)
<bytecode: 0x06bd04e8>
<environment: 0x06c7a5a8>

$g1431
function (v) 
.approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f)
<bytecode: 0x06bd04e8>
<environment: 0x06be62d4>
...
```

And i need to create a `call` to each of these functions procedurally.

I've tried with

```
g<-"g452"
eval(call(paste('initial[["',g,'"]]', sep=""), quote(t)))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "initial[["g452"]]"
```

And also

```
a[[1]] <- paste("initial[['",g,"']]", sep="")
a[[2]] <- quote(t)
eval(as.call(a))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  attempt to apply a non-function
```

How should I a do?

**NOTE:** I need to create only the `call`s that will be `eval`uated in a separate time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [mapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html):

```
> funs <- list(fn1 = function(x,y) x + y, fn2 = function(x,y) x * y, fn3 = function(x,y) x ** y)
> mapply(do.call, funs, list(list(1,2)))
fn1 fn2 fn3 
  3   2   1 
>
```

`mapply` will apply `do.call` to each function in the list, giving it the corresponding element of the second list as argument. The second list is list with one element (which is thus recycled), itself being a list of two arguments to map to `x` and `y`.

Alternatively, as @Jake suggests, you can use [lapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html):

```
> lapply(funs, function(f) f(1,2))
$fn1
[1] 3

$fn2
[1] 2

$fn3
[1] 1
```

to apply the anonymous function `function(f) f(1,2)` which takes a function as input and outputs the evaluation of the function with arguments 1 and 2, to each element of the list of functions.

A completely approach would be to create functions to be evaluated at a later stage:

```
> create.fun <- function(index, arg1, arg2) { return (function() funs[[index]](arg1, arg2))}
> create.fun("fn1",1,2)->f1
> create.fun("fn2",1,2)->f2
> f1
function() funs[[index]](arg1, arg2)
<environment: 0x102d12978>
> f2
function() funs[[index]](arg1, arg2)
<environment: 0x102d12e30>
```

Then, later,

```
> f1()
[1] 3
> f2()
[1] 2
>
```

Comment: I need to create the `call`s that will be evaluated in a different moment

Answer (score 0):

```
R> initial <- list(g425 = function(v) rnorm(v, mean = 10), g664 = function(v) rnorm(v))
R> initial
## $g425
## function (v)
## rnorm(v, mean = 10)
##
## $g664
## function (v)
## rnorm(v)

R> initial[["g425"]](1)
## [1] 9.963475
R> initial[["g664"]](10)
## [1] -0.195207690 -0.005614015 -1.588652593 -0.667482330 -0.386502730
## [6]  1.602831100 -0.044661135  0.522090969 -0.411569136  0.567418372
R> lapply(initial, function(f) f(5))
## $g425
## [1]  8.961135 10.982837  9.314733  9.850552 10.752787
##
## $g664
## [1] -0.3052389 -0.5199387  1.7668233  0.3558805  0.9558824
R> f <- initial[["g425"]]
R> foo <- call("f", 3)
R> eval(foo)

## [1]  8.890765 11.708142  9.368686
```

Comment: The same as @damienfrancois